# Contar caracteres enquanto digita

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um site de vendas e nele tem um produto **Letras** e cada letra custa R$10,00.

Como calcular o valor de uma frase que o cliente quiser comprar?

Por exemplo, se o cliente quiser comprar o nome dele, Betinho. O valor sairia por R$ 70,00 reais.

Como faço essa validação e contabilização através de um input?

Comment: Ola Betinho Silva, Só agora tive tempo de ver o que vc pediu lá no outro post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ao contabilizar o `length` da palavra o valor final também contabiliza os espaços.

**Agora não mais:**

```js
var espaco = 0;
$('#nome').focus();

$('#nome').keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) {
    espaco = 0;
    $('#nome').val("");
  }

  var text = $('#nome').val();

  if (text[text.length - 1] != ' ') {
    $('.preco').text((text.length - espaco) * 10 + ',00');
  } else {
    espaco++;
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Digite a palavra ou frase: <br><input id="nome" type="text" />

<div class='total' style='margin-top: 2%;'>
  Preço do produto R$: <span class='preco'></span>
</div>
```

Basta pegarmos a última posição da string e verificarmos se é igual a um espaço. No caso `' '`

Toda vez que existir um espaço ele adiciona +1 a variável `espaço` que será subtraída no valor final e multiplicada pelo valor de cada letra.

Também adicionei um trecho que detecta se o backspace ou o delete foram apertados. Dessa forma é possível resetar a variável `espaco` e limpar o valor do campo para que não haja erros na multiplicação.

Comment: E para eu pegar o "10" do banco de dados? Como faço

Comment: Depende de diversos fatores! Qual linguagem você usa para relacionar o html com o banco? php?

Answer (score 5):

Basta pegar o `length` da sua string.

```js
var str = "Betinho";
var n = str.length;
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa contar a quantidade de caracteres que tem o nome com a função `length`, porém essa função conta a quantidade de caracteres com espaços.

Para que os espaços não sejam multiplicados ao valor, podemos conta-los `split(" ").length - 1` para depois subtraí-los do cálculo.

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
function calcular(el) {
  const valor = document.getElementById('valor');
  const precoPorLetra = 10;
  const espacos = (el.value.split(" ").length - 1); //conta espacos
  const caracteres = el.value.length;
  valor.value = parseFloat( (caracteres - espacos) * precoPorLetra).toFixed(2); //formatado para duas casas decimais
}
```

```html
Nome: <input onkeyup="calcular(this)" type="text" />
Valor: <input id="valor" type="text" readonly />
```

Comment: Como eu faço isso sem ter q clicar em calcular... vai digitando e aparecendo o resultado já

Comment: Como está acima, utilizando o `onkeyup` na tag `input` do nome quando o usuário acaba de digitar a letra.

Comment: boa... apenas uma questão... está somando tbm o espaço em branco

Comment: Como eu pego esse valor  "10" do banco de dados?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode obter o tamanho de uma string através de seu campo `length`.

Logo, se você já tem a palavra e o preço, i.e.:

```
let palavra = "Betinho";
let precoUnitario = 10;
```

Então:

```
let valorPalavra = precoUnitario * palavra.length;
```

Já para pegar o valor do input, a forma mais fácil é com jQuery:

```
let palavra = $(idDoInput).val();
```

Ou sem jQuery, caso você tenha fetiche por código desnecessariamente longo:

```
let palavra = document.getElementById(idDoInput).value;
```

Comment: `$(idDoInput).val();` Caso ele não tenha muito conhecimento em Jquery esse trecho irá induzi-lo ao erro. O mais correto seria exemplificar da maneira correta `$('#idDoInput').val();`

Answer (score 2):

- Aceita somente letras, inclusive acentuadas (para não inflacionar os preços com virgulas, pontos, caracteres especias e etc :D )
- Separador de milhar `.` (ponto) e decimal `,` (virgula)
- Espaços são aceitos porém não são contabilizados

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.soLetras').keyup(function (el) {

      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]/g,''));
      var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
  
      var espacos = (nome.value.split(" ").length - 1);

      var letras = nome.value.length;      
      var total = parseFloat((letras-espacos) * 10).toFixed(2);
     
      total=total.replace(".", ",");
     
      $('.total').html("R$ " + (total).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")); 
     
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="soLetras" name="nome" id="nome" size="10" placeholder="Somente Letras">
<span class="total"></span>
```